# What are the default values for core_website, core_store_group and core_store?

Tags: magento-1.9, database, multistore

After I changed a few things on my database of core-website, core_store core_store_group, I was not longer able to connect my administration interface.

What are the default values of the three table (core-website, and core_store core_store_group)?

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select * from core_website;
+------------+-------+--------------+------------+------------------+------------+
| website_id | code  | name         | sort_order | default_group_id | is_default |
+------------+-------+--------------+------------+------------------+------------+
|          0 | admin | Admin        |          0 |                0 |          0 |
|          1 | base  | Main Website |          0 |                1 |          1 |
+------------+-------+--------------+------------+------------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.02 sec)

mysql> select * from core_store_group;
+----------+------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+
| group_id | website_id | name               | root_category_id | default_store_id |
+----------+------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+
|        0 |          0 | Default            |                0 |                0 |
|        1 |          1 | Main Website Store |                2 |                1 |
+----------+------------+--------------------+------------------+------------------+
2 rows in set (0.06 sec)

mysql> select * from core_store;
+----------+---------+------------+----------+--------------------+------------+-----------+
| store_id | code    | website_id | group_id | name               | sort_order | is_active |
+----------+---------+------------+----------+--------------------+------------+-----------+
|        0 | admin   |          0 |        0 | Admin              |          0 |         1 |
|        1 | default |          1 |        1 | Default Store View |          0 |         1 |
+----------+---------+------------+----------+--------------------+------------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```